# google cache showing wrong domain

Tags: php, html, caching

I have developed a website for my client putlockeris.co , everything is working fine, but when I opening link cache:putlockeris.co, it is opening Ichobots.net

Please tell me where I did a mistake, I googled it but no help found.

Comment: how new is your site?

Comment: sorry I didn't what you want to ask